# How to configure a Apache primary web server to handle the SSL connections from users (Tomcat Servlet/JSP container)

Tags: apache, tomcat, containers

How to configure a Apache primary web server to handle the SSL connections from users (Tomcat Servlet/JSP container)

Answer (score 1):

two steps:

- Configure httpd to connect to tomcat to "work" requests:
  http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html
- Configure httpd to use ssl:
  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/

LLP, Andrea